# Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to spawn multiple daemons (Android 4.1.2)

Tags: java, android, gradle

After importing an old android project from github which was running on API 23 (if I interpreted correctly), errors were displayed about the versions since I only have API 30 installed. So I installed that and now I'm getting this error

> [image: error]

After searching for long time, a solution which I saw at many places was to change the JDK location to JAVA_HOME, but doing that then gives the below error

> [image]

Being an absolute beginner, I'm not able to understand these errors or any posts here on stack overflow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

On a side note: The project that I am importing is the [multiscreen apps](https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/tree/Starter-code) course by Google on Udacity

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. After changing the sdk to java 1.8/11, I found I was missing Android SDK 29 (in my case). Installing the SDK from tools fixed my problem. It also showed this as a warning on build logs. Dont know why it was showing only the above issue.